# How to find the largest directories or largest files?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

Under Linux, I'm looking for a command to list the largest file and/or the largest directories under a directory.

Comment: The most useful tool I've found is xdiskusage (http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net) This shows graphically where the files are - by size. Great tool! (and it works directly with X11)

Comment: How this is duplicated of some question which has been closed as off-topic? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jcoppens Please post an answer, the tool is very good.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From any directory:

`du -a 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r`

Comment: this shows individual files, but the question is about directories as well

Comment: du with no arguments summarizes disk usage by directories.  du with -a produces the same directory information and includes the disk usage for individual files as well.

Comment: can't run sort when you're out of space :=(

Comment: This prints a lot of `du: cannot read directory './snap/core20/2015/var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied` when ran from root dir

Comment: You can redirect stderr to /dev/null to avoid those errors.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758924/633150

Answer (score 99):

A utility called `ncdu` will give you the information you are looking for.

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

On OS X, it can be installed using Homebrew:

```
brew install ncdu
```

Comment: +1 I'd never heard of this one before - worked great on the Mac too.

Comment: This is a much nicer solution than both of the higher answers.

Comment: This is mind-blowing. Suggest this over all other answers!

Comment: Fyi, this is an ncurses (text-based UI) application. So, no need to extensively discuss CLI parameters and whatnot; just install it and execute `ncdu` in the directory you'd like to analyze.

Comment: On CentOS, you can use this to install a repo containing ncdu:
`sudo yum install epel-release`

Comment: Great tool. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I always forget what this tool is called then spend ages searching the web for this post. Finally bookmarked it!

Answer (score 42):

Following command shows you one level of directories and their sizes

```
du --max-depth=1 /path | sort -r -k1,1n
```

If one of them really sticks out (the last one on the list is the largest due to `sort -r`), then you re-run the command on that directory, and keep going until you find the offending directory / file.

If all you want is the ten biggest files just do

```
find /home -type f -exec du -s {} \; | sort -r -k1,1n | head
```

Comment: biggest number ends up at the bottom for me no matter if I add `sort -r` or not.  Is there a way to get the biggest number at the top?

Comment: You must indicate to sort which column you want to sort by, and that it's numeric (not alphanumeric).  That's what -k1,1rn would do.  By default sort does uses alphanumeric sort on first column.

Comment: Yes, it's sorting correctly with that, but it's in ascending order low to high numbers no matter if I include `sort` or `sort -r`.  Am I misunderstanding how the -r works?  I guess it's not a big deal.  Your example is very helpful and got me the info I needed.

Comment: With the `sort` I have (`sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13` in Ubuntu 12.04.3) the option `-r` does not work if `-n` immediately follows `-k` (`-k1,1n`). This order of options works: `sort -rnk1,1`.

Comment: Great answer. On OS X the option is `-d 1` instead of `--max-depth 1`. What is also useful is `-m` which then reports in megabyte instead of block count.

Answer (score 8):

Following command will return top 10 biggest files from given `/path`

> du -a -h /path | sort -h -r | head -n 10

I like to use `-h` options for readability. Both `du` and `sort` need to have `-h`.

Answer (score 3):

> du -sk * | sort -nr | head -1

This will show the biggest directory/file in a directory in KB. Changing the head value will result in the top x files/directories.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-the-largest-filesdirectories-on-a-linuxunixbsd-filesystem/) will help you well:

```
cd /path/to/some/where
du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10
du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ls -A | xargs -I artifact du -ms artifact | sort -nr
```

Optionally, you can add a pipe and use `head -5`

Answer (score 0):

Use du.
Try this to order the result:

```
du | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one-liner (displays top-20 biggest files in the current directory):

```
ls -1Rs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -nr | head -n20
```

or with human readable sizes:

```
ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20
```

> The second command to work on OSX/BSD properly (as `sort` doesn't have `-h`), you need to install `sort` from `coreutils`.

So these aliases are useful to have in your *rc* files (every time when you need it):

```
alias big='du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20'
alias big-files='ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20'
```

Answer (score -5):

```
du -sh /path * | sort -nr | grep G
```

G for GIG (to weed out smaller) files/directories

Comment: This lists all the files and folders, showing the size. It doesn't sort the size by the K, M or G's worth of bytes, unless you GREP it as you shown

Comment: Also it will find anything with a `G` in the file's name.